# Change Mouse Cursor While Drag and Drop

Tags: javascript, dom, mouse-cursor

I have a DOM element that I want to drop "items" into. I want to give the user visual feedback with changing the cursor icon. But while mouse button is held down the cursor doesn't change. If I move the mouse no button, it changes. But not when I hold the button. Why? How can I achieve the desired cursor feedback for the user? I'm using Google Chrome.

```
<html>
    <head>      
        <script type="text/javascript">         
            function Document()
            {
                var that = document.createElement("div");
                that.style.backgroundColor = "#80ff80";
                that.style.border = "1px solid black";
                that.style.height = "90%";
                that.style.width = "50%";
                that.onmousemove = function (event)
                {
                    //console.log(event.offsetX + ", " + event.offsetY);
                    if (Math.random() < 0.5)
                        that.style.cursor = "not-allowed";
                    else
                        that.style.cursor = "move";
                    return false;
                }
                return that;
            }

            function onLoadPage()
            {
                var doc = new Document();
                document.body.appendChild(doc);
            }

        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="onLoadPage()" />
</html>
```

1) Move mouse over the div. It will randomly change cursor icons.
2) Press mouse button and move mouse over the div. It will keep the last icon until you release mouse button.

**Edit:**
Chrome's console might produce this issue. Cursor change seems to work well when I hide the "developer tools". When I enable "dev tools", change tabs to any tab and back, the cursor wont change with mouse button held down.

Comment: Are you appending the newly created element to the DOM?

Comment: Yes, of course. The green style is to see where it is and try out.

Comment: I [can't reproduce](https://jsfiddle.net/vjnh2wgr/) the issue ..?

Comment: OK. Firefox doesn't seem to have that issue. I was working with Chrome.

Comment: I tested with Chrome and Edge too, no reproduce. The title mentions drag and drop, could it be, that the cursor is not actually moving on the div, since the div in your real code follows the cursor? Or your real condition somehow fails (assuming you're detecting droppable elements under the cursor)?

Comment: I also just had a "no-issue" period. And I didn't change anything in the code. All I'm doing is switching browser between stack and my test page. Could be a focus thing?

Comment: It is possible, Chrome and FF are behaving differently when dragging the mouse from another browser window over the div (at jsFiddle FF works as expected, Chrome shows the default cursor), but both are showing the default cursor, if the mouse is dragged outside of the browser.

Comment: @Teemu Thanks for your time. I guess the dev tools produce the issue, See edit.

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to reproduce your issue but I came across the following link which also suggests a bug in all the browsers except firefox. It is an old link but may be helpful.

https://github.com/RubaXa/Sortable/issues/246